# MongoDB sort does not work

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query

since this morning (I think) I can't sort my collection. The collection has 26944 objects inside (it is currently my biggest - but that cant be the reason right?).

So what i'm doing:

```
myCollection.find().sort({ _id: 1 })
```

this works great and without any problem!
but:

```
myCollection.find().sort({ xxx: 1 })
```

each other case don't work, xxx means any other key on my object it does not matter which I take... 
for example:

```
myCollection.find({modified: { $exists : true } })
```

Returns an result with 26944 Objects,

```
myCollection.find({modified: { $exists : true } }).sort({"modified":-1})
```

will return 0 Objects.

Did I something wrong?
Maybe I had crashed my collection? Did somebody know what could do in this case? (excepts dropping the collection)

Example Object:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("55071e25760e250d050ed8d5"),
    "sysModified": new Date("2015-03-15T21:10:12+0100"),
    "created": new Date(1426529829922),
    "modified": new Date(1426528563945),
    "payments": [

    ],
    "orderItems": [
        {
            "orderId": 'xxxxx',
            "itemId": 'xxxxx',
            "ean": "XXXXX"
            "quantity": 1,
            "name": "xxxxxxx",
            "vat": 19,
            "price": 29.989999999999998437,
            "currency": "EUR",
            "_id": ObjectId("5507365c89866d820dcef7e0"),
        },
        {
            "orderId": 'xxxxx',
            "itemId": 'xxxxx',
            "ean": "XXXXX"
            "quantity": 1,
            "name": "xxxxxxx",
            "vat": 19,
            "price": 29.989999999999998437,
            "currency": "EUR",
            "_id": ObjectId("5507365c89866d820dcef7e1"),
        }
    ],
    "orderData": {
        "orderId": XXXXXXXXX,
        "type": "order",
        "status": "XXXXXXXXX",
        "timestamp_php": XXXXXXXXX,
        "customer": XXXXXXXXX,
        ...
    },
    "orderDeliveryAddress": {
        "customer": xxxxxxxxxxx,
        "company": "",
        "additional": "",
        "firstName": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "surname": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "street": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "houseNumber": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "zip": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "city": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "iso2": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "phone": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "fax": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "email": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    },
    "orderCustomerAddress": {
        "customer": xxxxxxxxxxx,
        "company": "",
        "additional": "",
        "firstName": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "surname": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "street": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "houseNumber": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "zip": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "city": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "iso2": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "phone": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "fax": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "email": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    },
    "__v": 1
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the data looks like, what it gets sorted like and what is your expected sort order?
btw. is there a key on the field you're sorting by?

Comment: See you cannot sort on a non-existent key so you need to be a lot more specific than what you are presently doing. Anything that "does not exist" has a predefinded value of `null` and therefore a pre-allocated sort order.

Comment: @Lunn, nothing special, i run that find command in shell, nodeJS and MongoHub (its an tool for mongo on osx) each one gives the same result (nothing).

Comment: Okay I got something,...  if I add an query (for find) it works, but not for all...

{'orderData.orderId': { $gt : 30000 } }

so i think i got an error on an object with lower orderId, but which error it could be?

Comment: Really unclear. The problem as I see it is that you are not sorting on a defined value in the way that it can. You need to make your intent clear in your question.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include 1) what indexes you have on the collection, 2) an examples of a query that does work with sort, 3) an explain for each of the queries? If you take some of the documents and insert them into a different collection, do finds and sorts work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It **is** possible that your collection is to big. If you try so sort on a key, that has no index this can result in an error if the resultset is to big. The error should look like this:

```
error: {
        "$err" : "too much data for sort() with no index.  
                  add an index or specify a smaller limit",
        "code" : 10128
}
```

What you can do is add an index to your key you want to sort by:

```
db.myCollection.ensureIndex({"modified":-1})
```

Or you reduce the resultset before sorting:

```
myCollection.find({modified: { $exists : true } }).limit(10).sort({"modified":-1})
```

Comment: Why would this apply given the question contains `.explain()` output that shows index usage? Not very observant.

Comment: @NeilLunn: I don't see any explain statement. Are you sure you are responding to the right question?

Comment: Possibly a misstatement by myself thinking of another question ( there are so many ) but I don't see that your "solution" here is anything other than what is already stated as an attempt in the question. Maybe they got it wrong. But in all likelihood the comments are more revealing in a response than a guess.